# Problems with left-recursion

Tags: xtext

I have a little grammar containing a few commands which have to be used with Numbers and some of these commands return Numbers as well.
My grammar snippet looks like this:

```
Command:
    name Numbers
    | Numbers "test"
;  
name:
    "abs"
    | "acos"
;

Numbers:
   NUMBER
   | numberReturn
;
    numberReturn:
        name Numbers
    ;
terminal NUMBER:
    ('0'..'9')+("."("0".."9")+)?
;
```

After having inserted the "Numbers 'test'" part in rule command the compiler complains about non-LL(*) decicions and tells me I have to work around these (left-factoring, syntactic predicates, backtracking) but my problem is that I have no idea what kind of input wouldn't be non-LL(*) in this case nor do I have an idea how to left-factor my grammar (I don't want toturn on backtracking).

EDIT:
A few examples of what this grammar should match:

```
abs 3;
acos abs 4; //interpreted as "acos (abs 4)"
acos 3 test; //(acos 3) test
```

Best regards
Raven

Comment: I don't know the parser generator you are using, but it looks to me like anything that starts with `name` is going to be ambiguous because with `name` as the starting symbol you can go either `Command` -> `name Numbers`... or `Command` -> `Numbers "test"` -> `Numbers: numberReturn` -> `numberReturn: name...`.

Comment: Yep that's it...Now I see it, too.  Now the question is how to solve this ambiguity. But thanks anyway

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? I think it covers it pretty well: http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html search for "Assigned Actions" and "Syntactic Predicates"

Comment: I literally tried to guess what your trying to do but I would need more details on your problem. What kind of statements would be possible in your DSL? Please add some examples, so I can figure out a possible grammar.

Comment: Added a few examples...Hope they are helpful enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar you are trying to achieve is left-recursive; that means the parser does not know how to tell between `(acos 10) test` and `acos (10 test)` (without the parentheses). However, you can give the parser some hints for it to know the correct order, such as parenthesized expressions.

This would be a valid Xtext grammar, with `test`parenthesized expressions:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model
    :   operations += UnaryOperation*
    ;

UnaryOperation returns Expression
    :   'abs' exp = Primary
    |   'acos' exp = Primary
    |   '(' exp = Primary 'test' ')'
    ;

Primary returns Expression
    :   NumberLiteral
    |   UnaryOperation
    ;

NumberLiteral
    :   value = INT
    ;
```

The parser will correctly recognize expressions such as:

- (acos abs (20 test) test)
- acos abs 20
- acos 20
- (20 test)

These articles may be helpful for you:

- https://dslmeinte.wordpress.com/tag/unary-operator/
- http://blog.efftinge.de/2010/08/parsing-expressions-with-xtext.html